# Extracting contents from the most inner parenthesis?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to convert this

```
(TOP (S (NP (NP (JJ Influential) (NNS members)) (PP (IN of) (NP (DT the) (NNP House) (NNP Ways) (CC and) (NNP Means) (NNP Committee)))) (VP (VBD introduced) (NP (NP (NN legislation)) (SBAR (WHNP (WDT that)) (S (VP (MD would) (VP (VB restrict) (SBAR (WHADVP (WRB how)) (S (NP (DT the) (JJ new) (NN savings-and-loan) (NN bailout) (NN agency)) (VP (MD can) (VP (VB raise) (NP (NN capital)))))) (, ,) (S (VP (VBG creating) (NP (NP (DT another) (JJ potential) (NN obstacle)) (PP (TO to) (NP (NP (NP (DT the) (NN government) (POS 's)) (NN sale)) (PP (IN of) (NP (JJ sick) (NNS thrifts)))))))))))))) (. .)))
(TOP (S (NP (DT The) (JJ interest-only) (NNS securities)) (VP (VBD were) (VP (VBN priced) (PP (IN at) (NP (QP (CD 35) (CD 1\/2)))) (S (VP (TO to) (VP (VB yield) (NP (CD 10.72) (NN %))))))) (. .)))
(TOP (S (NP (EX There)) (VP (VBD were) (NP (DT no) (JJ major) (NNP Eurobond) (CC or) (JJ foreign) (NN bond) (NNS offerings)) (PP (IN in) (NP (NNP Europe))) (NP (NNP Friday))) (. .)))
```

To the following sequence in which only the innermost open&close parenthesis pair of each scope is captured:

```
(JJ Influential) (NNS members) (IN of) (DT the) (NNP House) (NNP Ways) (CC and) (NNP Means) (NNP Committee) (VBD introduced) (NN legislation) (WDT that) (MD would) (VB restrict) (WHADVP (WRB how) (DT the) (JJ new) (NN savings-and-loan) (NN bailout) (NN agency) (MD can) (VB raise) (NN capital) (, ,) (VBG creating) (DT another) (JJ potential) (NN obstacle) (TO to) (DT the) (NN government) (POS 's) (NN sale) (IN of) (NP (JJ sick) (NNS thrifts) (. .)
(DT The) (JJ interest-only) (NNS securities) (VBD were) (VBN priced) (IN at)  (CD 35) (CD 1\/2) (TO to) (VB yield) (CD 10.72) (NN %) (. .)
(EX There) (VBD were) (DT no) (JJ major) (NNP Eurobond) (CC or) (JJ foreign) (NN bond) (NNS offerings) (IN in) (NNP Europe) (NNP Friday) (. .)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can print the line numbers of the matches and let `awk` join the lines

```
$ grep -oPn "\([^()]*\)" line | 
  awk -F: 'p==$1{a=a OFS $2} p!=$1{if(NR>1)print a;a=$2;p=$1} END{print a}'
```

> (JJ Influential) (NNS members) (IN of) (DT the) (NNP House) (NNP Ways)
>   (CC and) (NNP Means) (NNP Committee) (VBD introduced) (NN le
>   gislation) (WDT that) (MD would) (VB restrict) (WRB how) (DT the) (JJ
>   new) (NN savings-and-loan) (NN bailout) (NN agency) (MD can)  (VB
>   raise) (NN capital) (, ,) (VBG creating) (DT another) (JJ potential)
>   (NN obstacle) (TO to) (DT the) (NN government) (POS 's) (N N sale) (IN
>   of) (JJ sick) (NNS thrifts) (. .)

Comment: Nice but it ignores the first parenthesis (JJ Influential)

Comment: That would fail if a `:` appeared inside the inner parens.

Answer (score 1):

Look for sets of parentheses that don't contain other parentheses inside.

```
egrep -o '\([^()]*\)'
```

To keep the results on the same line, you could do:

```
while read line; do
    egrep -o '\([^()]*\)' <<< "$line" | tr '\n' ' '
    echo
done
```

Or using Perl:

```
perl -e 'while(<>) { my @m = $_ =~ /\([^()]*\)/g; print "@m\n" }'
```

(There must be a simpler way, but I'm drawing a blank.)

Comment: Is there a way to keep things in the same line they were found in the text? This spits them out as one (aaa aaa) in each line/

Comment: Can the input file contain multiple lines, or is it all in one line?

Comment: It contains multiple lines. I updated the question with a data snippet.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for FPAT all you need is:

```
awk -v FPAT='[(][^()]*[)]' '{$1=$1}1' file
```

e.g.:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[(][^()]*[)]' '{$1=$1}1' file
(JJ Influential) (NNS members) (IN of) (DT the) (NNP House) (NNP Ways) (CC and) (NNP Means) (NNP Committee) (VBD introduced) (NN legislation) (WDT that) (MD would) (VB restrict) (WRB how) (DT the) (JJ new) (NN savings-and-loan) (NN bailout) (NN agency) (MD can) (VB raise) (NN capital) (, ,) (VBG creating) (DT another) (JJ potential) (NN obstacle) (TO to) (DT the) (NN government) (POS 's) (NN sale) (IN of) (JJ sick) (NNS thrifts) (. .)
(DT The) (JJ interest-only) (NNS securities) (VBD were) (VBN priced) (IN at) (CD 35) (CD 1\/2) (TO to) (VB yield) (CD 10.72) (NN %) (. .)
(EX There) (VBD were) (DT no) (JJ major) (NNP Eurobond) (CC or) (JJ foreign) (NN bond) (NNS offerings) (IN in) (NNP Europe) (NNP Friday) (. .)
```

With other awks it'd just be a `while(match())` loop:

```
$ awk '{r=""; while (match($0,/[(][^()]*[)]/)) {r=r (r?OFS:"") substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)} print r}' file
(JJ Influential) (NNS members) (IN of) (DT the) (NNP House) (NNP Ways) (CC and) (NNP Means) (NNP Committee) (VBD introduced) (NN legislation) (WDT that) (MD would) (VB restrict) (WRB how) (DT the) (JJ new) (NN savings-and-loan) (NN bailout) (NN agency) (MD can) (VB raise) (NN capital) (, ,) (VBG creating) (DT another) (JJ potential) (NN obstacle) (TO to) (DT the) (NN government) (POS 's) (NN sale) (IN of) (JJ sick) (NNS thrifts) (. .)
(DT The) (JJ interest-only) (NNS securities) (VBD were) (VBN priced) (IN at) (CD 35) (CD 1\/2) (TO to) (VB yield) (CD 10.72) (NN %) (. .)
(EX There) (VBD were) (DT no) (JJ major) (NNP Eurobond) (CC or) (JJ foreign) (NN bond) (NNS offerings) (IN in) (NNP Europe) (NNP Friday) (. .)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also put a placeholder for the newlines, then delete the `grep` induced newlines and switch the placeholder back with `sed`:

`sed 's/.$/&_NL/g' file | grep -oP "\([^()]*\)" | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/_NL/\n/g'`